# Search similar address with SQL query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I need find addresses that are similar using an SQL query. I'm using Ruby on Rails.

This is the query I'm using:

`properties.where('lower(street_address) LIKE ?', "%#{params[:address].downcase}%")`

I have two properties with the following addresses:

`123 Happy st`
`123 East Happy st`

When I do a search (which is `params[:address]`) for `123 happy st`, i only get the first value.

If I do `east happy st`, i get only one

How can i formulate a query to get both records?

Comment: Do you want results that contains any of the words that you search for?

Comment: I realize searching addresses is more complicated than it initially seems. but we have a primary method to convert to lat/lng. this `LIKE` approach is a fallback. So I think searching the whole string for any of the words is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a case insensitive filter using a regular expression:

```
SELECT "properties".* FROM "properties" WHERE (street_address ~* '123|happy|st')
```

For that you need to split the `params[:address]` and join them with a pipe "|":

```
Property.where("street_address ~* ?", "123 happy st".split.join('|'))
```

Note, this matches both examples, but being a regular expression it could match anything else.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed "123 happy" will not return results, but I guess that's fine.

Comment: Really? In my case it does. I have only the examples you put in your question (`Property.where('street_address ~* ?', "123 happy".split.join("|")).pluck(:street_address) # => ["123 Happy st", "123 East Happy st"]`).

Comment: Oops, I forgot to get rid of the "%" between the term. Thank you sir!